# Length of the tensor product of two modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $M$ and $N$ are finite length $R$-modules, then $M \otimes_{R} N$ has finite length, and $\ell(M\otimes_{R}N)\leq\ell(M)\cdot\ell(N)$.

I've managed to prove the first part (i.e., $M\otimes_{R}N$ has finite length), but I don't know how to prove the inequality (I've tried to find a composition series for $M\otimes_{R}N$, but with no luck so far).

A complete answer, or just a few hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a short exact sequence $$0\to M'\to M\to M''\to 0$$ you get another one looking like $$M'\otimes N\to M\otimes N\to M''\otimes N\to 0 \tag{$\star$}$$ Suppose that $M$ has finite length and that $M'\neq0\neq M''$, so that $M'$ and $M''$ are also of finite length and, in fact, of length smaller than that of $M$. Inductively, you know that $\ell(M'\otimes N)\leq\ell(M')\ell(N)$ and $\ell(M''\otimes N)\leq\ell(M'')\ell(N)$. Use this and $(\star)$ to conclude what you want.

Comment: (If $R$ were a field (or $N$ flat) we could put a zero on the left of $(\star)$ and we would get exact multiplicativity. For a general ring the map $M'\otimes N\to M\otimes N$ is not injective, so we only get an inequality here)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, but if $M$ has length 1, we can't find that exact sequence $0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$ with $M'\ne0\ne M''$...

Comment: @Yecabel, indeed, what is written is the induction step of a proof.

Comment: Ok, but in my opinion this is not enough. It is not true that for a generic finite length module, you can find that sequence: for example, if the length is 1 (and this case was not analyze before inductive step).

Comment: @Losten, if $M$ has length $1$ then there is a surjection $R\to M$ and thus a surjection $R\otimes N\to M\otimes N$, so that the length of $M\otimes N$ is at most that of $R\otimes N\cong N$.

Comment: How do we use (⋆) in the proof, is it because it implies $l(M^\prime \otimes N)+l(M^{\prime \prime} \otimes N) \geq l(M \otimes N)$?