# Length of tensor product of finite length modules is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $M$ and $N$ are finite length $R$-modules, then $M\otimes_R N$ has finite length, and $l(M\otimes_R N) \le l(M)l(N)$.

I know the question has been posted previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409424/length-of-the-tensor-product-of-two-modules), but only half of it was answered and I do not understand the argument about the inequality.

I have tried to explicitly construct a composition series and use exact sequences, but in using the latter I can't see what modules to use in the sequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\{0\}=N_0<N_1<\cdots<N_n=N$ be a composition series for $N$. In particular, $N_i/N_{i-1}$ is a cyclic module, so $N$ can be generated by (at most) $n$ elements. Then there is a surjection $R^n\to N$, and tensorizing by $M$ we get $M\otimes_R R^n\to M\otimes_RN\to 0$. But $M\otimes_R R^n\simeq M^n$, so $M\otimes_R R^n$ has finite length which is greater or equal than the length of $M\otimes_RN$. Since the length of $M^n$ is $\ell(M)\ell(N)$, we are done.

Comment: How do we get $l(M^{\oplus n})\leq l(M)l(N)$?

Comment: Maybe I could write something like $0\subset (M_1,0,0,...)\subset (M_2,0,0,...)\subset ...\subset (M,0,0,...)\subset (M,M_1,0,...)\subset (M,M_2,0,...)\subset ...\subset M^{\oplus n}$?

Comment: I suggest you to revisit the definition of the length of a module.